# Regex to match N chars followed by another

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match the largest string (inside a string) with at most 5 chars but the last char has to be an X letter.

For example, I want the strings below to be converted to:

```
abXdef -> abX
abcdX-> abcdX
aXcdXf-> aXcdX
```

I am using PHP (but you can use any other language, no problem) and so far I came up with this:

```
preg_replace("/^(.{4})X.+$/","$1","abcdXef");
```

But it only works if the `X` is exactly at the fifth position. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried [RegExr](https://regexr.com/). It gives you the answer in the left pane.

Comment: So, `^(.{4,}X).+`? Four or more chars and then `X`?

Comment: Like `^.{0,4}X` https://regex101.com/r/fmzhDS/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex101 i came up with this

```
[a-zA-Z]{0,4}[X]
```

I made an edit to also get Uppercase letters

Comment: thx nice to hear it worked
https://regex101.com/
is a great tool to solve this kind of challenge

Comment: @Samul could you clarify why you accepted this answer? IMO it is incorrect! It matches strings of length 6 (5 characters, then X). Also it allows `x` alongside `X`. See: https://regex101.com/r/jql1jQ/latest.

Comment: He probably did cause it worked for his sample. I think you're right, I made some corrections regarding your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[a-zA-Z]{0,4}X
```

- `[a-zA-Z]{0,4}`: 0-4 letters preceeding the...
- `X`: ...exact letter X

See: https://regex101.com/r/GRXz8L/latest